# Android ImageView Overlap Touch Issue

Tags: android, image

I am having issue here with imageView touch. I have two imageview inside a FrameLayout. Consider both images are rectangle and overlap to each other.

- Image 1 is touchable, draggable and movable
- Image 2 is not movable

When I touch the Image 1 area, it will move correctly. However, when I touch Image 2 area which is overlap between Image 1, it cause the Image 1 to move. I have try to detect touch by Id and Tag but it is still saying I am touching Image 1

I want to prevent/restrict Image 1 from moving when touching Image 2 overlap area. How can I achieve this? Image 2 can be a custom shape, view or canvas also.

I am putting in XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frm"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTest1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:tag="img1"
            android:src="@drawable/a">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTest2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:tag="img2"
            android:src="@drawable/b">
        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Image 1 touch event

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (v.getTag() != null && v.getTag().equals("img1")) {
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                // Handle touch events here...
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(mid, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                        lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                        lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                        lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                        d = rotation(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            // ...
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                                    - start.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            }
                            if (lastEvent != null) {
                                newRot = rotation(event);
                                float r = newRot - d;
                                matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                                        view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add the code?

Comment: Hi Andreas. I have added the code

Comment: You are saying that image 2 is not movable. Is it touchable?

Comment: Nope. There are no touch event for Image 2. I have set Image 2 bringtoFront(), setClickable and setEnabled to false but same result. Touching anywhere inside FrameLayout will move Image 1 even there is another image blocking half view.

Comment: Please check the answer I gave below and if that doesn't fix your problem let me know. Though I am confident that the answer you are looking for is that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
 if (v.getTag() != null && v.getTag().equals("img1")) {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
```

You are checking if the tag of the view is equal to img1 and then do your work. However I can't see anywhere that you are checking if the view is equal to img2 (as stated in your xml).

You should add this after you are finished with your above if statement and do the appropriate work inside it:

```
else if (v.getTag() != null && v.getTag().equals("img2")) {
     //do work here           
 }
```

Comment: Hi Andreas. I don't want to move Image 2. It should always stay in front of Image 1. Imagine the Image 1 is my real photo and Image 2 is a photo frame with transparent rectangle in the center. I want to restrict Image 1 moving to its visible area only. For example, touching the rectangle photo frame should not move Image 1. Is there a better way to do this? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried creating your img2 in your xml before creating img1? This way will put img2 in the back and img1 in front. Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: Yes. I follow your instruction. Added touch event for Image 2 and it must return true. Now Image 2 not moving and only move Image 1 within its visible area. I did not know Android work like this. Thank you!